# Is there any possibilities to monitoring the Apache Flume using REST API & JMX?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am currently start working on Apache flume.I had installed the apache hadoop,java8 64 bit and Apache flume in same directory.

Now i need to monitoring the apache flume.

Is there any possibility to monitoring the Apache flume using REST API and JMX?

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus JMX Exporter or Jolokia can be added to Flume JVM arguments